# jQuery hide submenu when other menu is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I'm using [this](http://codepen.io/scottb/pen/gixIv) small script to create a horizontal menu with sub links. I have everything working but there is a small snag and that is I need the submenus to close when another submenu is clicked. You can see my menu [here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl/) I need it so that if you click menu one and then click menu two then the menu one sublinks disappear.

here is the jQuery for the menu:

```
$(function() {

// Dropdown toggle
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  }
});

});
```

Comment: Jsfiddle example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
$('.dropdown').css('display', 'none');
```

So before your next submenu opens, it closes all currently open.
Code:

```
// Dropdown toggle
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown').css('display', 'none'); //New code
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set that each click will removeClass .active from all .drop-down-items, and then add class active to the clicked item and then .dropdown-toggle:not('.active').hide()

Comment: if there was some jsfiddle snippet i could make it more simple but i hope you get my idea :)

Answer (score 0):

In your [custom.js](http://foley13.webfactional.com/sotl/wp-content/themes/sotl/js/custom.js?ver=20151215) you can change these lines:

```
 // On click sub menu
 $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
     $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
 });

 $(document).click(function(e) {
     var target = e.target;
     if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
         $('.dropdown').hide();
     }
 });
```

with:

```
//
// delegate the click event handler
//
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(e) {
    //
    // is current submenu visible?
    //
    var  isVisible = $(this).next('.dropdown').is(':visible');
    //
    // hide all submenu, not current
    //
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-toggle').next('.dropdown').hide();
    //
    // toggle the visibility of current menu: visible <--> invisible
    //
    $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle(!isVisible);
});
```